# Создание и запись в txt

Tags: c#, .net, файлы

```
private void bSaveLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String x = Game.choosen().name;
        String y = "Data\\" + x + ".txt";
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(y);           
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory("Data\\");
        if (file.Exists == false)
        {  
                file.Create();
                using (StreamWriter sw = file.AppendText())
            {                    
                sw.WriteLine("Hello");
                sw.WriteLine("And");
                sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
        }            
    }
```

Выдаёт:

> "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу..."

Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка заключается в том, что file.Create() создает и **открывает файл для записи**, в следствии чего строчка

```
using (StreamWriter sw = file.AppendText())
```

вызывает ошибку.
Попробуйте изменить эти две строчки на следующие:

```
using(FileStream stream = file.Create())
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
```

для того чтобы использовать имеющийся FileStream.